# How to solve 'TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined' with Apollo Graphql Client and React?

Tags: reactjs, postgresql, react-router, graphql, apollo

I'm trying to connect a deck URL to link to the cards list, similar to how I see it was done on [Traversy's SpaceX graphql demo](https://github.com/bradtraversy/spacex_launch_stats/tree/master/client/src).  I'm receiving the error **TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined** when clicking a link to either of the demo decks.

This is a React client I have built on top of the server, using Apollo with GraphQL connected to my functional PostgreSQL DB.  I've pinpointed the issue to what appears to be these lines, and how the props are being passed through React and Apollo.  Do note I am a beginner with GraphQL and Apollo, and this is my first real project with React, so any guidance to understanding the process would be appreciated.

```
let { id } = this.props.match.params;
id = parseInt(id);
```

Decks index.js

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    import gql from "graphql-tag";
    import { Query } from "react-apollo";

    import Loading from "../../Loading";
    import DeckItem from "./DeckItem";

    const GET_DECKS = gql`
      query DeckQuery {
        decks @connection(key: "DeckConnection") {
          edges {
            id
            deckName
            createdAt
            cards {
              id
              front
            }
          }
        }
      }
    `;

    class Decks extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <h1>Deck</h1>
            <Query query={GET_DECKS}>
              {({ data, error, loading }) => {
                if (loading) {
                  return <Loading />;
                }
                if (error) {
                  return <p>Error</p>;
                }

                const decksToRender = data.decks.edges;

                return (
                  <Fragment>
                    {console.log(data)}
                    {decksToRender.map(deck => (
                      <DeckItem key={deck.id} deck={deck} />
                    ))}
                  </Fragment>
                );
              }}
            </Query>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Decks;
```

DeckItem index.js

```
    import React from "react";
    import Moment from "react-moment";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    export default function DeckItem({ deck: { id, deckName, createdAt } }) {
      return (
        <div>
          <div>
            <h2>
              <Link to={`/deck/${id}`}>{deckName}</Link>
            </h2>
            <p>Description coming soon...</p>
            <h5>
              Created on <Moment format="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm">{createdAt}</Moment>
            </h5>
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
```

Cards index.js

```
    import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react";
    import gql from "graphql-tag";
    import { Query } from "react-apollo";
    import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

    import Loading from "../../../Loading";

    const CARDS_QUERY = gql`
      query CardsQuery($id: ID!) {
        deck(id: $id) {
          id
          deckName
          cards {
            id
            front
            back
          }
        }
      }
    `;

    export class Cards extends Component {
      render() {
        let { id } = this.props.match.params;
        id = parseInt(id);
        return (
          <Fragment>
            <Query query={CARDS_QUERY} variables={{ id }}>
              {({ data, error, loading }) => {
                if (loading) {
                  return <Loading />;
                }
                if (error) {
                  return <p>Error</p>;
                }
                const {
                  id,
                  card: { front, back }
                } = data.deck;
                return (
                  <div>
                    <ul>
                      <h1>
                        <li>
                          <span>Id:</span> {id}
                        </li>
                      </h1>
                      <h4>Details</h4>
                      <li>Front: {front}</li>
                      <li>Back: {back}</li>
                    </ul>
                    <hr />
                    <Link to="/">Back</Link>
                  </div>
                );
              }}
            </Query>
          </Fragment>
        );
      }
    }

    export default Cards;
```

Relevant React router routes

````
    ```
    import { Router, Route } from "react-router-dom";
    ```
    import FlashCardPage from "../FlashCards";
    import Cards from "../FlashCards/Cards/CardsItem";

    import * as routes from "../../constants/routes";

      <Router>
           ```
          <Route
            exact
            path={routes.FLASHCARDS}
            component={() => <FlashCardPage />}
          />
          <Route exact path={routes.CARDS} component={() => <Cards />} />
        </div>
      </Router>
````

the path in my routes file is "/deck/:id"

Console Error log

```
            react-dom.development.js:19782 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
                at Cards.render (index.js:23)

                index.js:1452 The above error occurred in the <Cards> component:
                in Cards (at App/index.js:42)
                in component (created by Route)
                in Route (at App/index.js:42)
                in div (at App/index.js:19)
                in Router (at App/index.js:18)
                in App (at withSession.js:8)
                in Query (at withSession.js:6)
                in Unknown (at src/index.js:84)
                in ApolloProvider (at src/index.js:83)
```

The result should be a deck showing a list of the cards, '/deck/1' should show 2 or 3 cards from my PostgreSQL server.  Currently I can only see the decks with a url, but upon clicking, it throws up the error immediately.  Other Graphql functions are working correctly, and using Playground the query works just fine, so it seems I'm not passing props correctly.  Any additional information needed, I'll be happy to provide.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `Route` component from `react-router-dom` uses the **render-prop** pattern to extend the component it renders, providing it `props`. <sup>[[1]](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.3.1/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L116)</sup>

It forwards these `props` (`match`, `location`, `history`, and `staticContext`) to the `React.Component` that is passed for its `component` prop when it renders. <sup>[[2]](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/v4.3.1/packages/react-router/modules/Route.js#L118)</sup>

In the routes you defined this isn't passed to the `FlashCardPage` or `Cards` component because there is stateless function component that wraps them.

```
<Route exact path={routes.CARDS} component={() => <Cards />} />
```

This stateless function component is passed these props; you can take responsibility to forward these `props` down to `FlashCardPage` and `Cards` components.

```
<Route exact path={routes.CARDS} component={(props) => <Cards {...props} />} />
```

However, I recommend to get rid of the stateless component which wraps the component rendered in the `Route` since it's redundant.

```
<Route exact path={routes.CARDS} component={Cards} />
```

Comment: Thanks, your instructions worked perfectly and helped me understand why I couldn't get it to work!  Your advice about ridding of the stateless component I will certainly follow as well.